# Как отловить в пользовательской функции gRPC Graceful shutdown

Tags: golang, rpc

Есть небольшой пример:

```golang
func main() {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", Opt.GRPC.Addr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    signalChan = make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(signalChan, syscall.SIGTERM)
    s := grpc.NewServer()

    //...

    go func(){
        if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()
    killSignal := <-signalChan
    switch killSignal {
        case syscall.SIGTERM:
            s.GracefulStop()
    }
}
```

Серверу gRPC отправляется сигнал SIGTERM. В данной реализации сервер ждет выполнение пользовательской функции, по окончанию выполнении пользовательской функции приложение завершает работу.
Как можно поймать сообщение в пользовательской функции, что серверу необходимо завершится?

Answer (score 1):

[Судя по нынешнему коду](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/5ba054bf3709c0a51d1ed76f68d274a8c1eef459/server.go#L1214), `GracefulStop` никак не оповещает серверный контекст о вызове. У вас остаются следующие варианты:

1. Использовать `Stop`, который более груб, но зато отменяет контекст.
2. В структуре вашего сервера добавить отдельный контекст и отменять его перед вызовом `GracefulStop`.

Comment: Собственно так и сделано, добавлен собственный контекст, не очень это изящно. А грубое прерывание выполнение тоже не хотелось бы. Транзакцию к БД надо корректно остановить, чтоб она под контролем была. Подумал, может знает кто-нибудь как это сделать